# The length function is finitely subadditive

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing, right-continuous function. For $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$, let $\ell_\alpha(a,b]=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$. Suppose we have $a,b,a_1,b_1,...,a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $a_i<b_i$ for all $i,1\leq i\leq n$, such that $$(a,b]\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(a_i,b_i]$$
>
> Prove that $$\ell_\alpha(a,b]\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ell_\alpha(a_i,b_i]$$

Just using the fact that $(a,b]$ is contained in a union of intervals, letting $a'=\smash{\displaystyle\max_{1\leq i\leq n}} \lbrace a_i\rbrace$ and $b'=\smash{\displaystyle\min_{1\leq i\leq n}} \lbrace b_i\rbrace$, we know that $a' \leq a$ and $b \leq b'$.

Since $\alpha$ is non-decreasing, we then have $\alpha(a') \leq \alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b) \leq \alpha(b')$.

So I can at least get this far, although after this I don't have any ideas. Any hints would be appreciated (but no solutions please!)

EDIT: I found that, if I make the assumption that $a' \leq b'$, then I can get the result as follows: $\alpha(a_i)\leq \alpha(a')$ and $\alpha(b')\leq \alpha(b_i)$ for all $1\leq i\leq n,i\in\mathbb{N}$, so $\alpha(b')-\alpha(a')\leq \alpha(b_i)-\alpha(a_i)$ for all $i$. Using the inequalities that I had before this edit, we can get $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\leq \alpha(b')-\alpha(a')$, so the result follows immediately from here.

I still don't think this is a correct proof, though, because I don't think we can assume $a'\leq b'$ without losing generality. We could re-label the $a_i$ and $b_i$ so that this assumption is true, but this might make some of the intervals $(a_i,b_i]$ undefined, no?

Comment: For your $a',b'$ you have $(a', b'] = \bigcap_i (a_i, b_i]$, not the union. Hint: Try an example with $n=2$ first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried a couple examples and it seems like $a' \leq b'$ should always be true, but I can't see a way to prove it

Comment: What are you're $a'$ and $b'$? Still the maximum over the $a_i$ and minimum over the b_i$? What about $(0, 1] \cup (1,2]$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(0,1] \cup (2,3]$ for $a'> b'$

Comment: But the union of those two intervals isn't an interval, and there also cannot be an interval that crosses the "gap" between them - at least, graphically, it seems so

Comment: Why not? The statement does not claim that the union is connected.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying. I'm thinking about abandoning my $a'$ and $b'$ idea and trying induction, but I can't really see how it would go after making the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Again. Try to understand the $n=2$ case. What happens if both intervals are disjoint? What happens if they aren't?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29654/discussion-between-ducky-and-user251257).